# Traversing in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I want to create a firebase hierarchy as an image shown in the following link

http://i44.tinypic.com/ifv22x.jpg

I tried and failed to do the following:

Count the number of children (*trip_id*s) under a *user_id* and assign *trip_id = count+1* to a new trip. *numChild()* works only on *DataSnapShot*. How can we count number of *trip_id*s using *user_id* Firebase reference?

Later, I want to traverse through each *trip_id* and retrieve the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't recommend counting manually in order to create new trip IDs. In a distributed context where multiple clients might be writing data there'll often be conflicts.

Use the `ref.push()` method to automatically create unique, chronologically incremental IDs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Later, if I want to traverse through, how can I do it with anonymous ID.

Comment: You can just use the 'child_added' event handler to get all the trip IDs.

Comment: I understood DataSnapShot in a wrong way. Assume that my firebase obj referencing to trip_list/user_id. Could you please write the logic to read the children

Comment: Got the solution. ref.on('child_added', function(...){...}); works great.